With Next.js, can I make a subdirectory also a standalone app?
I have a Next.js where the app is located in //.../src/app and hosted on MyFakeDomain.com. I have two separate multi-page javascript games that live in separate subdirectories –

/src/app - main page that has links to the subdirectories
/src/app/number-game - a game where you guess numbers
/src/app/block-game - a game like tetris

So I can currently go to MyFakeDomain.com/number-game and MyFakeDomain.com/block-game, but now I want to create a separate website for block-game, e.g. FakeBlockGame.com.
Is there a setup where I can have block-game both as a subdirectory of a larger Next.js app as well as the top-level directory of a second Next.js app?

Have you tried using multi zones?

I have looked into it. My understanding is zones are parallel constructs but my goal is to allow a nested directory within a Next.js project also be the head directory for a separate Next.js project so I can serve that code twice, once independently as its own app on its own domain and once in the larger aggregate app in that larger domain
